# re pattern - Find an expression located after two criteria

Tags: python, python-re

I have this string :
`"ALPHABET, LETTER_A=a;0, LETTER_B=b;1, LETTER_C=c;2"`

I need a pattern to get each match to be the data.

I have already found some patterns.

- to get `"a"` as match: `r"(?<=LETTER_A=)([^;]+)"`
- to get `"b"` as match: `r"(?<=LETTER_B=)([^;]+)"`
- to get `"c"` as match: `r"(?<=LETTER_C=)([^;]+)"`

But for `1`,`2` or`3`, I can't find a pattern whose match just returns `1`,`2` or`3`. The logic would be to find first `"LETTER_B="`, then find the first `";"` after that and collect everything between that and a `","` or the end of the string.

I tried this: `r"(?<=(?<=LETTER_A=)\w;)(.*?)(?=,|$)"`and the match is `1` which is what I want but if the string is `"ALPHABET, LETTER_A=aa;0, LETTER_B=b;1, LETTER_C=c;2"` [The changement is only adding a char to `a`], it does not work anymore.

By match, I mean what I get when I do `match.group()`, not `match.group(1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `findall` and use `.*?` so your matches aren't greedy.

Grabbing `c;2` a little more difficult since it doesn't have a comma, so we optionally look for end of string `$` there.

```
s = "ALPHABET, LETTER_A=aa;0, LETTER_B=b;1, LETTER_C=c;2"

patt = "LETTER_[A-Z]{1}=.*?;(.*?)(?:,|$)"

re.findall(patt, s)
```

Comment: Hi, what i want is after `;` not before. And not include `;` or `,`

Comment: I see, I got thrown off by you matching a, b, and c earlier. I've updated the answer.

Comment: With your solution, `match.group()=LETTER_A=aa;0,` and `match.group(1)=0`. What I wanted was `match.group()=0`. But don't worry, I'll modify my script to go with your solution.